# Replacement of outliers with median in R

Tags: r

Looking for the help,

After replacing the outliers with the median also still I am getting the outliers in the boxplot.

what needs to be done I don't want to remove the outliers I just want to replace the outliers.

here I am sharing my code

```
attach(mba)

quan<- quantile(mba$workex ,probs = c(.25,.75))

range<- 1.5*IQR(mba$workex)

median(mba$workex) 

ravi<- mba

ravi[mba$workex<(quan[1]-range)]<-52

ravi[mba$workex>(quan[2]+range)]<-52

boxplot(ravi$workex)

unique(boxplot(ravi$workex)$out)
```

I will be very thankful.

Comment: When you enforce an incorrect distribution assumption (and sometimes even if you don't) and remove/change outlier values, other values can be identified as outliers by outlier tests. What you are doing with your outliers is a BAD idea. Every inference from your data will be invalid. Predictive performance (if that's what you are after) will also suffer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that will work (but do take @Roland's warning about the sought replacement seriously):

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c(sample(1:10, 9), 1000),
  v2 = c(runif(9), 2000),
  v3 = c(11111, rnorm(8), 23450))
```

Which values are outliers?

```
boxplot(df)$out
```

Locate/detect in dataframe:

```
sapply(df, function(x) x %in% boxplot(df)$out)
```

Replace outliers by median, e.g., in the third column:

```
df$v3[df$v3 %in% boxplot(df)$out] <- median(df$v3)
```

Here are the two boxplots, the first before the substitution, the second after it: the outliers in the third column shown in the panel on the **right**, have clearly gone, as can be seen in the panel on the **left**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code. But still, I am getting the outliers            
boxplot(mba$workex)$out

sapply(mba$workex, function(x) x %in% boxplot(mba$workex)$out)

mba$workex[mba$workex %in% boxplot(mba$workex)$out] <- median(mba$workex)

boxplot(mba$workex)